# Ajax and Django - returning a json object to a template

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, django

What I'm trying to do is to update a part of my web app with Ajax but I can't seem to know how to pass the Json object back to the template when what I want to update is an array of chars created at the initial loading of the page.

Views.py

```
def caesarHomePage(request):
cipher = alphabet()
x = cipher.getListLetter()
y = cipher.getListLetter()

if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "GET":
    print("Inside Request!")

    form = caesarCipher(request.GET or None)

    if form.is_valid:

        print(request.GET.get('the_key'))
        integerKey = int(request.GET.get('the_key'))

        y = cipher.setCipherLetters(integerKey)


        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(y), content_type="application/json")


else:
    form = caesarCipher(request.POST or None)

context = { 'x': x,
            'y': y,
            'form': form,
}


return render(request, 'HomeCaesar.html', context)
```

Main.js

```
    $("#keyButtonId").on({
click : function() {
    var variable = document.getElementById('id_key');
    console.log(variable.value)
    $.ajax( {
      url : "http://127.0.0.1:8000/HomeCaesar/",
      type : "GET",
      data: { CSRF: 'csrf_token',
              the_key: $('#id_key').val()
            },

      success : function(json) {
        //  $('#id_key').val('0');
          alert(json);
          console.log(json);
          $('#alteredAlphabet').html(json.y);
          console.log("FUNCTION CALLED!");
      }

    });

}
```

});

HTML I want to update:

```
  <div id="alteredSection">
      Altered Alphabet: <br>
      {% for y in y %}
          <input id="alteredAlphabet" type="text" name="letter{{ y }}" size="1"  value = {{ y }}> <br>
       {% endfor %}

  </div>
```

How do I update my `y` variable in my HTML when using Ajax? Am I returning correctly to Ajax or should I return directly to the template?

Comment: json.y is an array ? and you are using "id" (alteredAlphabet) inside a loop it make multiple text box with same id, id must be unique

Comment: is this legal:  {% for y in y %}

Comment: I manage to fix it, had to take the html part that was going to be updated by Ajax out of the original html and use the {% include "html path" %} and in the views.py return with render() using the html file which had what I wanted to update. Then in the Ajax function, use $('targeted ID').html(json)

PS. Now myy CSS don't want to update. :S Haven't touch it in a while and today I had to do some div placement and Django wont notice those changes. Any tips?